# Create string of 7-bit ASCII text from 8-bit ASCII chars in C++

Tags: c++, string, bitset

I wish to create a string with up to 46 octets, filled in with 7-bit ASCII chars. For example, for the string 'Hello':

1. I take the last 7 bits of 'H' (0x48 - 100 1000) and put it in the first 7 bits of the first octet.
2. I take the next char 'e' (0x65 - 110 0101), the first bit will go to the last bit of the first octet then it will fill the next 6 bits of octet 2.
3. Repeat 1-2 until end of string, then the rest of the octets will be filled in with 1's.

Here is my attempt which I have worked quite a bit on, I've tried using bitset but it seems that it is not appropriate for this task as I do not have to have 46 octets all the time. If the string can fit in 12 (or 24, 36) octets (and just have the rest filled in by 1's) then I do not have to use 46.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    std::string a = "Hello";
    int N = 0;
    if (a.size() <= 11) {
        // I'm supposed to implement some logic here to check if it
        // will fit 12, 24, 36 or 46 octets but I will do it later.
        N = 80;
    }

    std::vector<bool> temp(N);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<bool> chartemp(a[i]);

        cout << a[i] << "\n";
        cout << chartemp[0] << "\n";
        cout << chartemp[1] << "\n";
        cout << chartemp[2] << "\n";
        cout << chartemp[3] << "\n";
        cout << chartemp[4] << "\n";
        temp[j++] = chartemp[0];
        temp[j++] = chartemp[1];
        temp[j++] = chartemp[2];
        temp[j++] = chartemp[3];
        temp[j++] = chartemp[4];
        temp[j++] = chartemp[5];
        temp[j++] = chartemp[6];
    }

    for (int k = j; k < N; k++) {
        temp[j++] = 1;
    }

    std::string s = "";
    for (int l = 0; l <= temp.size(); l++)
    {
        if (temp[l]) {
            s += '1';
        }
        else {
            s += '0';
        }
    }    
    cout << s << "\n";

}
```

The result is

```
000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110
```

Comment: It's probably simplest to operate on 8-byte integers rather than on individual bytes.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between `"Hello"` and `"Hello\x7f"`? Both would be represented in the same way. Did you mean to include the null terminator too, or do you want to disallow that character?

Comment: @DanielH: I read the question as the extra `1`s wont be added until the next full octet, not starting after the last encoded bit, so `"Hello"` would be `10010001 10010111 01100110 11001101 11100000 11111111 11111111 ...`, whereas `"Hello\x7f"` would be `10010001 10010111 01100110 11001101 11111111 11000000 11111111 ...` instead.

Comment: What is 8 bit ASCII?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then what about `"Daniel H"` vs `"Daniel H\x7f"`? The string `"Daniel H"`, encoded in 7 bits per character, would end at the end of the 7th octet. It is difficult to avoid all ambiguity; [SMS does something similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7-bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38), so you can’t end a text message with a multiple of 8 characters total with a carriage return (not that you would usually want to), and I *think* the original spec made it so you couldn’t end the message with an `@` (which you might want).

Comment: @EvilTeach A convenient way to say “ASCII chars encoded in the seven low-order bits of an octet with the high-order bit set to 0”. It isn’t technically correct but it is usually perfectly understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if you expect statement `std::vector<bool> chartemp(a[i])` to copy the `i`'th character of `a` as a series of bits into the vector. Yet the constructor of a vector interprets the value as the initial size, and `a[i]` is the ASCII-value of the respective character in `a` (e.g. `72` for `'H'`). So you have a good chance to create vectors of larger size than expected, each position initialized with `false`.

Instead, I'd suggest to use bit-masking:

```
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 6);
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 5);
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 4);
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 3);
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 2);
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 1);
    temp[j++] = a[i] & (1 << 0);
```

And instead of using `temp[j++]`, you could use `temp.push_back(a[i] & (1 << 0))`, thereby also overcoming the need of initializing the vector with the right size.

Comment: Thank you, just had to reverse the numbers to work (0 -> 6, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string stuffIt(const std::string &str, const int maxOctets)
{
    const int maxBits = maxOctets * 8;
    const int maxChars = maxBits / 7;

    if (str.size() > maxChars)
    {
        // t0o many chars to stuff into maxOctes!
        return "";
    }

    std::vector<bool> temp(maxBits);
    int idx = temp.size()-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        char ch = str[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
            temp[idx--] = (ch >> (6-j)) & 1;
    }

    int numBits = (((7 * str.size()) + 7) & ~7);

    for (int i = (temp.size()-numBits-1); i >= 0; --i) {
        temp[i] = 1;
    }

    std::string s;
    s.reserve(temp.size());

    for(int j = temp.size()-1; j >= 0; --j)
        s.push_back(temp[j] ? '1' : '0');

    return s;
}
```

`stuffIt("Hello", 12)` returns:

> 100100011001011101100110110011011110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

`stuffIt("Hello", 24)` returns:

> 100100011001011101100110110011011110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

`stuffIt("Hello", 36)` returns:

> 100100011001011101100110110011011110000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

`stuffIt("Hello", 46)` returns:

> 10010001100101110110011011001101111000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

If you want to know how many octets a given string will require (without adding octets full of `1`s), you can use this formula:

```
const int numChars = str.size();
const int numBits = (numChars * 7);
const int bitsNeeded = ((numBits + 7) & ~7);
const int octetsNeeded = (bitsNeeded / 8);
```

If you want the extra `1`s, just round `octetsNeeded` up to the desired value (for instance, the next even multiple of 12).